# How to store previous suite results(index.html)/ How to copy results(index.html) in a different folder with a different name

Tags: xml, ant, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm suing Selenium Webdriver + TestNG + ANT.

Everytime when I run my suite file: build.xml which is integrated with testNG.xml, the output file index.html overwritten by the new generated report file.

In short how can I save the results of TestNG+ANT without overwriting previous result in selenium?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by creating a new test-ouput folder for each run. Refer to Cedric's reply in this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/ESnCcUSeWGA)